# Can Powershell Tools for Visual Studio 2015 projects make Project References

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

I have a Powershell Tools for Visual Studio 2015 project that is a script module.  I would like to add a project reference to a .NET 4.5 class library that is also a project in the same solution.  From a visual perspective the dependency is listed under the references tree in the powershell project but it has the warning overlay icon on it.  When running the pester tests they error out with a type resolution error (`Cannot find type [IHE.Cda.TrifoliaParser]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`).  I cannot find any documentation which indicates whether what I am attempting is even possible.  Thus my question is whether it is possible or if the references list is just a artifact of being in visual studio.

**Solution Explorer View**

[image: Project Reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The References are an artifact of VisualStudio. It would be possible to generate an `Import-Module <PathToThe>.dll` line on top of every script in your project, but that's very obtrusive, and not every script will need all the dependencies.

Comment: Is a good rule of thumb that script modules should only reference BCL types and when needing to reference 3rd party assemblies a binary module should be used?

Comment: Never heard of such rule. Don't get mislead by the name, the Module in `Import-Module` can mean PowerShell module `.psm1` or PowerShell binary module `.dll` or any other .NET DLL `.dll`. In this case it's just a simpler way of saying `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("<PathToThe>.dll")`